# Grails: how to handle JSR 303 bean validation

Tags: java, grails, bean-validation

I'm using Java entity classes as domain objects in Grails application. These classes have JSR 303 validation annotations (@Size, @NotEmpty etc.).

Grails controllers and views work fine with these entity classes, but when I try to save an instance with broken constraints (empty value for @NotEmpty field), I get an error page with the following:

```
/webcall-account-manager-2/company/save
Class
javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException
Message
Validation failed for classes [com.rcslabs.webcall.server.model.Company] during persist time for groups [javax.validation.groups.Default, ] List of constraint violations:[ ConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='may not be empty', propertyPath=name, rootBeanClass=class com.rcslabs.webcall.server.model.Company, messageTemplate='{org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotBlank.message}'} ]

Around line 27 of grails-app/controllers/com/rcslabs/webcall/server/model/CompanyController.groovy
24:    def save() {
25:        def companyInstance = new Company()
26:     companyInstance.properties = params
27:        if (!companyInstance.save(flush: true)) {
28:            render(view: "create", model: [companyInstance: companyInstance])
29:            return
30:        }

Trace
    Line | Method
->>  251 | call      in org.grails.datastore.gorm.InstanceMethodInvokingClosure
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|     27 | save      in CompanyController.groovy
|   1110 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    603 | run       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    679 | run . . . in java.lang.Thread
```

What can be done to handle it in a proper way (message box above the field)?

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure, as I've never used JSR 303 and Grails, but you could probably call .validate before the save.  When you call .save it is running the validation, and that appears to be throwing an exception.  So try doing the validate call manually, then you should be able to return the error(s) in a similar fashion that you use in your if block.

Comment: companyInstance.validate() returns true